# How to write text file in thread-PHP

Tags: php, pthreads

I am not able to write a text file in thread using php pthreads extension.but the same piece of code can perform DB insert operation successfully. 
PHP Version: 5.6
Kindly Refer following code and suggest changes required:

```
class MyThread extends Thread
{
    private $wallet;
    private $std;
    public function __construct($wallet,$std)
    {
        $this->wallet = $wallet;
        $this->std = $std;
    }
    public function run()
    {
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
        if ($conn->connect_error) 
        {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 
            $sql = "INSERT INTO test1 (data) VALUES ('TID:".Thread::getCurrentThreadId()."')";
            $conn->query($sql);
            file_put_contents("abc.txt","ABCD");
    }
}
$wallet = "ABC";
$std = "DEF";
$pool = new MyThread($wallet,$std);
$pool->start();
```

Thank you in Advance. :)